# Build maven multimodule project in JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a parent Maven project (pom packaging) and 4 Maven modules (jar packaging) as children of that. Is there any way/plugin to create a importable dependency of the parent project including all the children? I mean that I want to create some kind of abstraction, so when somebody wants to import my project, it won't be necessary to import a specific childermodule (the module that he will use), he will just import the whole project (all the children modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maven **parent project** corresponds with *inheritance*. It is meant the children projects to *inherit* the settings, so you do not have to repeat them and you may set all the common stuff in a single place.

On other side, the convenience Maven project **containing dependencies** corresponds with *composition*.

You should not mix these two things together. Parent project is a common *super-class* of your modules. This convenience project you wish to have is a *collection* containing all your modules as dependencies. You should not want the the`Animal` class to *depend* on all the animals.

Just accept the fact that you need two separate Maven projects:

1. the parent (if you need it), and
2. the convenience project for transitive dependencies.

The solution for your problem is described e.g. here: [3.6.1. Grouping Dependencies](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html)

> If you have a set of dependencies which are logically grouped together. You can create a project with pom packaging that groups dependencies together. For example, let’s assume that your application uses Hibernate... Every project which uses Hibernate might also have a dependency on the Spring Framework and a MySQL JDBC driver. Instead of having to include these dependencies in every project that uses Hibernate, Spring, and MySQL you could create a special POM that does nothing more than declare a set of common dependencies. You could create a project called persistence-deps (short for Persistence Dependencies), and have every project that needs to do persistence depend on this convenience project.

Comment: Thanks for answering! My problem is I want to use my parent project as an All-In-One persistence-deps for the sub-modules (children) not for external project dependencies. As far as I know you cannot reference a submodule as a dependency on the parent pom. Can you help?

Comment: Don't use the parent project as the All-in-one-dep, but create another pom just for this purpose. You will have 2 poms - one as the parent for all your modules, another as the covenience project fot all-in-one dependencies.

Comment: Ok, I will try it :)

Comment: The parent pom will be of packaging `pom` which means it does not produce any kind of `jar` file which contradicts your idea of using the parent as all in one dep. If you like to use a module as a dependency you have to use that module...Importing a whole project does not make sense cause a project can contain several artifacts like jar, war, ear's which are not intended to be used as dependencies...

Comment: @khmarbaise As the link I posted says: "You can now add this project as a dependency and all of its dependencies will be added as transitive dependencies to your project. When you declare a dependency on this persistence-deps project, don’t forget to specify the dependency type as pom." So you do not have to specify 10 dependencies, but only 1. However, the modules you depend on will come packaged in separate artifacts.